# How to find the solutions to this modular equation: $-2131\cdot 3^x\equiv y\pmod{1763}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider:

$-2131\times 3^x\equiv y\pmod {(43\cdot 41)}$, with $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

I found this solution:

$x=2+168\times s$, with $s$ positive integer, for example.

For $x=2$, $y=214$.

Is there any other $y$ for which a solution $x$ exists?

How can I find all the solutions?

Comment: $3$ has order $168 \pmod{41 \cdot 43},$  so you are getting about one $y$ that works out of each ten values

Comment: and   $$ -2131 \cdot 206 + 1763 \cdot 249 = 1 $$

Comment: Any positive integer $x$ will produce an infinite number of solutions $y = -2131\cdot 3^x + 1763k$ for all sufficiently large $k$ to make the expression positive.

Comment: $-2131\equiv1\bmod41$

Answer (score 0):

Solution in pari/gp:

```
erd()=
{
 m= Mod(3, 1763);
 h= znorder(m);
 print("\nMultiplicative order of "m" is "h"\n");
 S= [];
 for(y=0, 1762,
  x= znlog(y/(-2131), m, h);
  if(x, S= concat(S, [[x,y]]))
 );
 S= vecsort(S);
 print("[x, y] = "S)
};
```

Output:

```
Multiplicative order of Mod(3, 1763) is 168

[x, y] = [[1, 659], [2, 214], [3, 642], [4, 163], ... [165, 1227], [166, 155], [167, 465]]
```

---

Verify for $(x,y)$=`[2, 214]`:

`Mod(-2131,1763)*Mod(3,1763)^(2+168*0)`=`Mod(214, 1763)`

`Mod(-2131,1763)*Mod(3,1763)^(2+168*777)`=`Mod(214, 1763)`

i.e. $-2131\cdot 3^{2+168\cdot k}\equiv 214\pmod {1763}$, where $k$=`0,1,2,3,...`

---

Verify for $(x,y)$=`[167, 465]`:

`Mod(-2131,1763)*Mod(3,1763)^(167+168*0)`=`Mod(465, 1763)`

`Mod(-2131,1763)*Mod(3,1763)^(167+168*77777)`=`Mod(465, 1763)`

i.e. $-2131\cdot 3^{167+168\cdot k}\equiv 465\pmod {1763}$, where $k$=`0,1,2,3,...`